# detect if variable is of sympy type

Tags: python, sympy, isinstance

I have a variable which may or may not be a sympy class. I want to convert it to a float but I’m having trouble doing this in a general manner:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2014, 19:10:20) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
>>> import sympy
>>> x = sympy.sqrt(2)
>>> type(x)
<class 'sympy.core.power.Pow'>
>>> y = 1 + x
>>> type(y)
<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
>>> z = 3 * x
>>> type(z)
<class 'sympy.core.mul.Mul'>
>>> if isinstance(z, sympy.core):
...     z = z.evalf(50) # 50 dp
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

I will be testing `x`, `y`, `z` to convert into a float. note that I can't just run `evalf()` on `x`, `y` and `z` without checking because they might be integers or floats already and this would raise an exception.

---

`sympy.sympify()` unfortunately does not convert to float. if it did then that would be the ideal solution to my problem:

```
>>> sympy.sympify(z)
3*sqrt(2)
>>> type(sympy.sympify(z))
<class 'sympy.core.mul.Mul'>
```

Comment: Why not just `sympify` it?

Comment: If all the `sympy` types you're dealing with have the `evalf` method, then maybe you want `try: z= z.evalf(50); except AttributeError: # Code to handle plain ints/floats`.

Comment: @tzaman `sympify()` does not output a float afaik

Comment: @mulllhausen according to the [docs](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/core.html#sympy.core.sympify.sympify), it should: `it will convert python ints into instance of sympy.Rational, floats into instances of sympy.Float, etc.`

Answer (score 9):

All sympy objects inherit from `sympy.Basic`.  To evaluate an sympy expression numerically, just use `.n()`

```
In [1]: import sympy

In [2]: x = sympy.sqrt(2)

In [3]: x
Out[3]: sqrt(2)

In [4]: x.n()
Out[4]: 1.41421356237310

In [5]: if (isinstance(x, sympy.Basic)):
   ...:     print(x.n())
   ...:     
1.41421356237310
```

Comment: well didn't know that all sympy objects inherit from `sympy.Basic`.

Comment: It's in a well hidden portion of the docs http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=basic#module-sympy.core.basic.  It might be somewhere else too but I can't find it at the moment

Comment: Note, that at least in my version of Sympy, matrices are not instances of `sympy.Basic`.

Answer (score 0):

heh, at the end of the day, it turns out you can just convert a sympy object to float using python's native float conversion function! don't know why i didn't try this straight away...

```
>>> import sympy
>>> x = sympy.sqrt(2)
>>> float(x)
1.4142135623730951
```

i will use this since it works even if `x` is a python int or already a python float